# ¿Como puedo recorrer un array de json, obtener sus valores para mostrarlos en la vista?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3

```
function nuevaPartidaVenta() {
    var ticket = $('#ticket').val();
    if (ticket != null && validaFormPartidaVenta()) {
        //$(".agregar_partida_catalogo").hide();
        var style_edit = 'style="width: 100%;"';
        var url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>facturas/Facturas/getPartidaFactura'
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: 've_id_venta=' + ticket,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(resp) {
                var valores = JSON.stringify(resp);
                console.log(valores);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Controlador

```
function getPartidaFactura()
{
    $ve_id_venta = $this->input->post('ve_id_venta');
    $partidas = $this->ventasModel->getPartidasVenta($ve_id_venta);
    echo json_encode($partidas);
}
```

Salida por consola

```
[  
   {  
      "id_partida_venta":"38",
      "pa_cantidad":"1",
      "pa_unidad":"Caj‌​a ",
      "pa_descripcion":"Duvalin",
      "pa_precio":"200",
      "pa_importe":‌​"200",
      "pa_descArt":"‌​0",
      "pa_status":"1",
      "‌​pa_fecha_registro":"‌​2017-02-10",
      "pa_id_v‌​enta":"14",
      "pa_id_pr‌​oducto":"190",
      "tipoD‌​esc":"null",
      "impDesc‌​Art":"0",
      "descArt":"‌​0",
      "pa_descripcion_p‌​artida":"",
      "pa_clave‌​_producto":"DV500"
   }
]

[  
   {  
      "id_partida_venta":"39",
      "pa_cantidad":"1",
      "pa_unidad":"Caj‌​a ",
      "pa_descripcion":"Paginas Web",
      "pa_precio":"1800",
      "pa_importe":"1800",
      "pa_descArt":"0"      ‌​,
      "pa_status":"1",
      "pa‌​_fecha_registro":"20‌​17-02-10",
      "pa_id_ven‌​ta":"14",
      "pa_id_prod‌​ucto":"187",
      "tipoDes‌​c":"null",
      "impDescAr‌​t":"0",
      "descArt":"0"      ‌​,
      "pa_descripcion_par‌​tida":"",
      "pa_clave_p‌​roducto":"tai1"
   }
]
```

Comment: Coloca el codigo de tu controlador en CodeIgniter para saber que esta devolviendo la llamada ajax.

Comment: Este es mi controlador

function getPartidaFactura(){
     $ve_id_venta = $this->input->post('ve_id_venta');
     $partidas     = $this->ventasModel->getPartidasVenta($ve_id_venta);
  echo json_encode($partidas);


    }

Comment: Que muestra en consola?

Comment: @CesarVieyra no hubiera sido mejor que edites tu pregunta y agregas el código de tu controlador y la información de los JSON.

Comment: @CesarVieyra al menos date un tiempo de dar un recorrido al `Centro de Ayuda` y puedas redactar bien una pregunta. http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

El resultado que recibe en el [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) al momento de definir el `dataType` a `json` automáticamente lo convierte a un objeto JSON.

Al momento de utilizar [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) estás convirtiendo un objeto a una cadena JSON. En tu caso no es necesario.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var cadenaJSON = '[{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},  {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},{"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}]';

var menus = JSON.parse(cadenaJSON); // objeto JSON

// A modo de ejemplo, recorrer con un for
for(var indice in menus){
  console.log(menus[indice].value);
}

// Mostrar el objeto como cadena
console.log(JSON.stringify(menus));
```

---

Otra de la manera simplificada es utilizar [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), que realiza una petición con el verbo `GET`. Utilizando [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) para recorrer dentro del resultado.

Por ejemplo:

```js
(function() {
  var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
    tags: "mount rainier",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
        $( "<img>" ).attr( "src", item.media.m ).appendTo( "#images" );
        if ( i === 3 ) {
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="images"></div>
```